# WPF ProgressBar going from 100% to 1%

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a WPF progressbar which I want to report the progress of transferring bytes of a stream to a database. However, I divide the bytes left by total and multiply it by 100:

```
    int percentage = (int) (streamlength / BytesLeft) * 100;
```

So basically its going from 100 to 1, is there a way I could represent this on a progressbar?

```
  <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="723,204.2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="411" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="pbStatus" Value="{Binding BytesToDatabase, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

If not, I will change the calculation.

Comment: its going from 100 to 1 ???

Comment: @Sayse: A typo I guess, otherwise it won't compile at all.

Comment: Sorry it is a typo, its a silly question from me, probably best to be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch the two (`streamlength` and `BytesLeft`):

```
int percentage = (int) (BytesLeft / streamlength) * 100;
```